# How to write attributed grammar in YACC?

Tags: yacc

I currently started studying YACC. I just want to know how to write an attributed grammar in YACC. Please give an example. Can we use union ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can associate attributes with the nodes in the parse tree. Each node has a single attribute, the "dollar specifier".
Here is an example, where the attribute is used for the value of an expression:

```
expression : expression '+' expression { $$ = $1 + $3; }
           | expression '-' expression { $$ = $1 - $3; }
           | NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
           ;
```

By default, this single attribute is an integer, but you can change the type using the *%union* directive. Different types of nodes can have different types of attributes. (This is why it's called *%union* and not something like *%type*.) If you need more than one attribute, you can use a C struct  or struct pointer as the type.

Comment: you don't use attributes: it shuld looks like $1->value

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use some C++ features: for AST tree storage use "symbolic" class set, based on `Sym` **abstract** class. Virtual inheritance gives you ability to use `Sym*` pointers and `dynamic_cast<Num*>(o)` for STL containers and object manipulations. Use `attr{}` map for grammar attributes.

Full (c)lexical program skeleton(c) source tree see at https://github.com/ponyatov/uc/tree/master/ast

```
struct Sym {        // universal algebraic symbolic type, struct applies public
    string tag;         // class/type marker, required for token elements
    string val;         // value, string is universal can represent _any_ data

    Sym(string T,string V);     // <T:V> pair constructor
    Sym(string V);              // token constructor

    vector<Sym*> nest;          // \ nest[]ed elements for AST tree
    void push(Sym*o);           // / push new nested element

    map<string,Sym*> attr;      // \ named dynamic attributes,
    double num ;                // / or extra attributes you need

    virtual string head();      // return "<T:V>" pair repr
    string pad(int);            // pad output of tree elements
    string dump(int depth=0);   // return tree dump
};

struct Num: Sym { Num(string);      // number tokens
    double val; string head(); };
struct Str: Sym { Str(string);      // 'string' tokens
    string head(); };

struct Vector: Sym { Vector(); };   // [vector]
struct Op: Sym { Op(string); };     // operator

typedef Sym*(*FN)(Sym*);                        // \ primitive function
struct Fn: Sym { Fn(string V, FN F); FN fn; };  // /

                                // == lexer interface ==
extern int yylex();             // get next token
extern int yylineno;            // line number
extern char* yytext;            // parsed lexeme (ASCIIZ string)
#define TOC(C,X) { yylval.o = new C(yytext); return X; } // gen.token macro
                                // == syntax parser interface ==
extern int yyparse();           // grammar parser
extern void yyerror(string);    // error callback function
#include "ypp.tab.hpp"          // shared lex/yacc token definitions
```

Note lexer interface macro used in lpp.lpp for token construction in form

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?([eE](\+\-)?[0-9]+)?   TOC(Num,NUM)    /* number */
```

For answer see above grammar must be described as

```
%defines %union { Sym*o; }
%token <o> NUMBER ADD SUB
%type <o> expression

expression : expression ADD expression {
    // build AST node
    $$=$2; $$->push($1); $$->push($3);
    // synth .num attribute from nested nodes
    $$->num = $1->num + $3->num ;
    }

expression : expression SUB expression {
    // build AST node
    $$=$2; $$->push($1); $$->push($3);
    // synth .num from nested nodes
    $$->num  = $1->num - $3->num ;
    }

expression : NUMBER { $$=$1; } /* terminal should be used directly */
```

or if you want true symbolic way: this yacc grammar will do **dynamic** synthesable attributes in `attr{}` (much cryptic in C++, but looks clear in Python+PLY syntax)

```
%%
REPL : | REPL ex { cout << $2->dump() << endl; } ;

ex : SYM                { $$=$1; /* terminal as is */ } ;
ex : NUM                { $$=$1; /* terminal as is */
    // synth
    $$->attr["num"] = new Num(dynamic_cast<Num*>($1)->val);
    } ;

ex : SYM LP ex RP       { $$=new Op("@");               // apply operator
                          $$->push(new Fn($1->val));    // new function
                          $$->push($3);                 // parameters
    // synth
    if ($1->val=="sin")
        $$->attr["num"] = new Num(std::sin(\
            dynamic_cast<Num*>($3->attr["num"])->val));
    } ;

ex : LP ex RP           { $$=$2; /* as is */ } ; // must be after SYM(ex)

ex : ex DIV ex          { $$=$2; $$->push($1); $$->push($3);
   $$->attr["num"] = new Num(\
    dynamic_cast<Num*>($1->attr["num"])->val \
    / \
    dynamic_cast<Num*>($3->attr["num"])->val \
    );
   } ;
```

gives tree

```
<op:=> #0x5b1180
    <sym:A> #0x5b1118
    <op:+> #0x5b1348
        <op:-> #0x5b11e8
            1 #0x5b1250
                num =
                    1 #0x5b12a8
        <op:*> #0x4a07d8
            <op:+> #0x5b13b0
                2.3 #0x5b1418
                    num =
                        2.3 #0x5b1470
            <op:^> #0x4a1090
                4e-005 #0x4a1010
                    num =
                        4e-005 #0x4a1050
                <op:/> #0x5bb730
                    num =
                        -0.0399165 #0x5bb850
                    <op:@> #0x5bb648
                        num =
                            -0.279415 #0x5bb6d0
                        <fn:sin> #0x5bb680
                        6 #0x5bb570
                            num =
                                6 #0x5bb5b0
                    7 #0x5bb768
                        num =
                            7 #0x5bb7a8
```

(*) to answeres: please note attribute grammar keyword in quiestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples of yacc grammars around the web.  A simple google search for [yacc example](https://www.google.com/search?q=yacc%20example&aq=f&oq=yacc%20example) brings up lots of links.  There's also a bunch of useful links [here](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I you prefer simplest way, yes, use this grammar: :
@https://github.com/ponyatov/uc/blob/master/ast/union.yacc

This variant still build **annotated** AST tree, but attributes hardcoded into classes. Use virtual inheritance if you need extra attributes, and track attributes tree validity by hands (by production rules).

```
%defines %union {
    struct AST {
        string name;
        double value;
        virtual string dump(int depth=0);
        vector<AST*> nest; void push(Sym*);
    } *node;
}

/* tokens name/value must be filled in lexer */

%token <node> SYM NUM EQ ADD SUB MUL DIV POW LP RP
%type <node> ex  
                    // precedence down higher
%right EQ
%left ADD SUB
%left MUL DIV
%right PFX

%%
REPL : | REPL ex    { cout << $2->dump() << endl } ;

ex : SYM            { $$=$1; } ; // token as is
ex : NUM            { $$=$1; } ; // token as is

ex : ADD ex %prec PFX {
    $$=$1; $$->push($2);                // unary operator AST subtree
    $$->value = + $2->value;            // + A
    };
ex : SUB ex %prec PFX {
    $$=$1; $$->push($2);                // unary operator AST subtree
    $$->value = - $2->value;            // - A
    };

ex : ex ADD ex      {
    $$=$2; $$->push($1); $$->push($3);  // build AST subtree
    $$->value = $1->value + $2->value;  // synth attr without cryptic code
    } ;

ex : ex MUL ex      {
    $$=$2; $$->push($1); $$->push($3);  // build AST subtree
    $$->value = $1->value * $2->value;  // synth attr without cryptic code
    } ;
```

Really, `yacc-ng` should support %struct option to build AST trees directly this like, but `yacc` can't do this, and you should nest `struct*` in `%union`.